# Pointer to Visual Format Language (VFL) Constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm wondering if it is possible to obtain a pointer to a constraint created through the use of visual format language.

For a simple example, assume I have created an array of constraints for a view such that it is pinned to the top, left and bottom of it's super view, but has a width of 100, and I wanted to obtain a pointer to this width constraint to change it later programmatically.

The VFL for that would be something along the lines of:

```
UIView *insertedView = [[UIView alloc] init];
insertedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview: insertedView];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(insertedView);
NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"viewWidth" : @(100.0) };

NSArray *constraintsH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[insertedView(viewWidth)" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];

NSArray *constraintsV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[insertedView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

[self.view addConstraints: constraintsH];
[self.view addConstraints: constraintsV];
```

Is it possible to obtain an instance of NSLayoutConstraint pointing to the width constraint of 100.0 in the above example?

I know I could go about it the other way, by creating the width constraint separately via constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant, but I'm curious if there is a method for doing this with pure VFL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with `NSArray`'s `- objectAtIndex:` and `- indexOfObjectPassingTest:`:

```
NSUInteger index = [constraints indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ((NSLayoutConstraint *)obj).firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth;
}];

NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [constraints objectAtIndex:index];
```

If you have multiple width constraints (such as at different priorities, for example), you can just make the test in the block more specific.

Comment: Awesome, in all my time developing iOS apps I've never come across this method on NSArrays, cool stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to set a constraint's identifier property with VFL. This would probably be the quickest way to grab the constraint in question using your method.

Comment: Agreed. I was originally looking to find a way to do that, since I think it's the most straightforward, but I can't see from the documentation how it could be done.